# Can I srore email & password on my class code not database for jwt token generate

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, bearer-token, asp.net-apicontroller

I want to store my credintial like **email** and **password** hardcode on my code, when I create jwt token then I want to use it. Can I do this??

If it possible how to access email and password.

Comment: Possible yes. Recommended NO!

Comment: **This is my conditional statement.**

if (_userData != null && _userData.Email != null && _userData.Password != null)

**If i put value that if condition?
like **
if (_userData != null && _userData.Email == "example@mail" && _userData.Password == "1234")
**it's good??**

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can use credentials class and some collection of them in memory.
Secondly, you can use database

**But:** It is in general not recommended to store the user's password anywhere without encryption

Example: User -> Max@gmail.com, Password -> qwerty123 must be stored as: Max@mail.com and pass as *awofi12312ASOIFDAOSF@?@?"!£!"*. No matter where: in memory, in db.

For usage you must also implement decryption in order to check credentials from encrypted value to it's decrypted state (from -> awofi12312ASOIFDAOSF@?@?"!£!" to -> qwerty123)

Comment: It's just learning purpose, I know it not good practice to store credential without encryption. if i want to store which procedure need to follow?

Comment: Use hash rather than encryption for password.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the settings file to overcome this problem. Go to the Add New Item window and select the settings file. Then it will open a table and put "email" and "password" to identify the references. And also you need to select the data type and if you want to add a default value, you can add that one here too.

So you can read data by this line,

```
bool dataSaved = savedSetting.Default.dataSaved;
```

And also you can write data by this code,

```
savedSetting.Default.dataSaved = true;
            savedSetting.Default.Save();
```

Comment: So everyone that can get its hands on that file can read the user and the password?

Comment: Yes. If you use the correct reference to retrieve data, you can access the data.